# Can I prepend the argument list in call/2?

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

[call(Goal,Arg)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call/2) allows to append the argument Arg to the arguments of Goal and call the resulting goal, e.g.

```
call(succ(1), R).
```

is the same as

```
succ(1, R).
```

However, I don't want to append to the argument list, but instead prepend, e.g.

```
callpre(succ(1), R).
```

should result in

```
succ(R, 1).
```

How can I prepend arguments to the list of Goal's arguments and call the resulting goal?

Comment: [Similar question for `maplist`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582088/is-there-a-better-method-than-making-a-new-rule-to-change-variable-order-for-map). I would prefer an answer that is not "use that library" though, which is what we get for that question.

Comment: Your description of `call/2` in the first sentence of your question is not correct. `call/2` does not takes a list of arguments to `Goal` in its second argument. It take a single additional argument to `Goal`, as you then describe correctly.

Comment: @Eyal thank you, fixed it.

Comment: @Fatalize The question you linked already shows how to do it _without_ a library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitrary number of arguments, you could define it as

```
callpre(MGoal, Arg) :-
    strip_module(MGoal, M, Goal), 
    Goal =.. [F | Args],
    NewGoal =.. [F, Arg|Args], 
    M:NewGoal.
```

You'll also need a `meta_predicate/1` declaration for this:

```
:- meta_predicate callpre(1, *).
```

Comment: Your meta_predicate declaration is well meant but inaccurate. It rather should be `:- meta_predicate(:, *)`.  A `1` alone means that one argument is missing **and** that one has to call it with `call(G_1, A_1).` It is this second part that you are violating.

Comment: @Boris: can you elaborate?

Comment: Also you need to handle modules. With your declaration, `(:)/3` is called.

Comment: @false I don't understand what you mean by using `:` instead of `1` in the `meta_predicate` declaration. The SWI Prolog documentation says that `:` means `The argument is module-sensitive, but does not directly refer to a predicate. For example: consult(:)`. As for the problem with `(:)/3', thanks, I've fixed the answer.

Comment: `1` means: the argument must be called with one additional argument with `call/2`.  But you are adding the additional argument in the beginning. Therefore cross-referencing will not work accurately.

Comment: I see. I thought the cross-referencer is just concerned with the arity of the predicate, not the order of the arguments. What's an example of something that would not work accurately?

Comment: @Eyal: It makes a significant difference, if the predicate itself is again a meta-predicate: Then, the arguments get shifted/rotated by one for the analysis. So some undefined predicates are missed, and others are incorrectly considered predicates etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could define that as:

```
callpre(Goal,Z):-
  Goal=.. [Predicate, Y],
  Goal2=.. [Predicate, Z],
  call(Goal2,Y).
```

if Goal has more than one arguments you could write:

```
  callpre(Goal,Z):-
     Goal=.. [Predicate,Arg1| Y],
     reverse([Arg1|Y],[H|T]),
     reverse(T,T1),
     Goal2=.. [Predicate,Z| T1],
     call(Goal2,H).
```

(this also works for one argument)

Note that `=../2` operator unifies a functor and arguments with a list e.g `succ(X,Y)=.. [succ,X,Y]`.

Comment: Thanks for the typo and  the correction !!, edited the post.